# Why is a reference to a polymorphic class, polymorphic?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, language-lawyer

It is a well known fact that the snippet below prints `Derived` or something similar.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>
class Base { public: virtual ~Base(){} };
class Derived : public Base{};
int main()
{
     Derived d;    
     Base& b = d;
     std::cout << typeid(b).name() << '\n';
}
```

But I'd like to understand how could one conclude this, from paragraph §5.2.8/2 in the Standard (N4140). For example, `b` is certainly a glvalue, but the type `Base&` is not the same as `Base`, so I can't say that `b` is polymorphic. What am I missing?

Comment: _"What am I missing?"_ The role of `virtual` in the declaration.

Comment: That just tells me that `Base` is polymorphic, but it doesn't tell me that a reference to `Base`, i.e., an object of type `Base&` has a polymorphic class.

Comment: For a class to be polymorphic it must have at least one virtual function. With no virtual functions there is no v-table, thus no virtual fuction calls or dynamic typing is possible. "b" could still be a reference to an instance of Derived, but you couldn't tell that by examining b, using typeid, or calling its members.

Comment: @joeking vtables are implementation details.  In a [tag:language-lawyer] question, implementation details are ... secondary.  And even though someone else added it, this is very much a language-lawyer question.

Comment: "an object of type Base& has a polymorphic class": Well, yes, because "Base" is a polymorphic type - meaning that its possible that instances could be instances of subclasses of Base - but they aren't required to be ... "b" could be a reference to an object that is an instance of Base.

Comment: v-table are an implementation detail, but the existance or not of virtual functions still has the effects I described. See §10.3/1 "Virtual functions support dynamic binding and object-oriented programming. A class that declares or
inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class."

Comment: The type of an expression is *never* a reference type.  `b` is an lvalue of type `Base`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [expr]

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” (8.3.2, 8.5.3), the type is adjusted to T prior to
>   any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the
>   expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.

The expression `b` initially has type "reference to `Base`", so the type is adjusted to `Base`. It is an lvalue, which is a glvalue.

From [class.virtual]:

> A class that declares or inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class.

`Base` declares a virtual function, so it is a polymorphic class.

From [expr.typeid]:

> When `typeid` is applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a polymorphic class type (10.3), the result refers
>   to a `std::type_info` object representing the type of the **most derived object** (1.8) (that is, the dynamic
>   type) to which the glvalue refers.

Based on the above, we satisfy the initial conditions (the expression is a glvalue whose type is a polymorphic class type), so we pick the most derived object to which `b` refers to. That would be `d`, which has type `Derived`.

If `b` were a `Base` instead of a `Base&`, then the most derived object would be `b` itself.

Comment: But the expression `b` in the example has type `Base&`. How does one conclude that `Base&` is the type of a polymorphic class?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet Because we don't care that it's a reference. Added an extra clause.

Comment: That's it. §5/5 is the answer. Thanks(+1)